# list comprehension in python (struggling to understand the logic)

Tags: python

SOF community.

I am attempting to delete the last character within a string and to replace it by 'ies' using list comprehension.

What the below expression attempts to do is just that:
delete last character using index position and concatenate it with 'ies' afterwards.

```
word = [(word.del[-1]) + 'ies' for character in word]
```

new to code. Apologies if logic is off (which im sure it is)

Comment: You don't need list comprehension for this. Use a slice

Comment: Even more, list comprehension is not an appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Your problem description doesn't even involve lists, so why would you use a list comprehension?

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys. How exactly do I approach this?

Comment: You just need most of ‘word’ plus another string. Do you know about slices?

Comment: not exactly quamrana. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: like this ? `word [:-1] + 'ies'`

Comment: I'm a seasoned "old fart" in computer programming, and I still look up things about Python and other languages that i've forgotten many times in the past.  Google is an amazing tool for this.  It most cases, it will find the primary Python documentation for a specific function/concept along with a bunch of tutorials.  In this case, I strongly recommend that you simply google "python slice".  You'll have links to many resources to help you learn all about them.

Comment: @Steve, thanks bud. Ive been blasted with a great deal of content in my postgrad program. It is hard to contain the basics when they spend just a 2 week period explaining this before jumping into ML.. Drowning !

Comment: I get it.  I'd still caution you to not "learn" a concept in a way that you don't really understand it.  Like here, you're being shown `word[:-1]`, but it isn't really being explained. Slices are one of the coolest and most powerful features of Python that doesn't exist in other languages.  I'd strongly suggest that you try to really understand how it works.  Basically, it's `[<start index>:<end index>:<step>]`, negative index values mean to count from the end of the string rather than the beginning (the last character of a string has index `-1`), and the `<end index>` is exclusive.

Comment: ...missing values have defaults: `0` for first, `<length of string>` for second, `1` for third.  So `[:-1]` is the same as `[0:-1:1]`, which means take the beginning of the string to the end of the string, but don't include the last character of the string since the character pointed to by the second index `(-1)` is not included.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's take a string

```py
s = 'lady'
```

Now, in python, string is `immutable`. By that, it means you can not alter the string variable `s` once it is created. So what effectively you want to to do is to take all the characters of `s` until but not included the last character `y` and add `ies` at the end.

Now, the copy can be done using `slicing operator`

```py
new_s = s[:-1] + "ies"
```

Comment: if for example i wanted to slice by the last 2 positions, would it look like

new_s = s[0:-1] + 'ies' ?

Comment: new_s = s[:-2] + 'ies' if you to slice by last 2 positions

Answer (score 2):

the expression `word = [(word.del[-1]) + 'ies' for character in word]` has syntax errors, and doesn't do what you think it does:

`word.del[-1]` it is not correct to use brackets [] to pass arguments to a method

`word.del[-1]` if word is a string, it has no method called del(), you can use del(object) to delete an object thou

assuming the syntax is correct, what this list comprehension does is that it takes each character in the word and makes a list of them such that each one will have 'ies' appended to it, for example if `word='abc'` the this will produce `['aies','bies','cies']`

if you want it to "delete last character using index position and concatenate it with 'ies' afterwards." you dont the list comprehension at all:

```
>>> word = 'abc'
>>> word = word[:-1]+'ies'
>>> print(word)
abies
```

what `word[:-1]+'ies'` does is that it takes a slice of word variable from the beginning until the last index (exclusive) and as a result the last character will not be included.

Comment: Solid. This is all making sense. Cheers for the explanation over my 'list comprehension'

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing for this:

```
word[:-1] + 'ies'
```

This takes all but the last character and adds "ies" to it

Comment: just got it, thanks for the confirmation. I will apply it now!